# Story ID: a woman missing the train and living among strangers

Tags: identification-request

I would like your help to find a story I read some years ago.

What I remember about the story is that it's set in a western style world in the 1800 century probably in USA.
The story begins by following a young woman who is sent away from her close family to stay with a relative who lives across the country. She goes by train and somewhere along the way, the train makes a stop at a small western town.
The girl gets off the train to use a public toilet in the town and because some kids are teasing her, she fails to get back to the train before it departures and is thus stuck in the town. She ends up staying at either the town mayor, the doctor or a more or less outlaw woman. Again... As I recall it.

Can you please help identify this story?